# I am trying to use code to read an integer from a text document and am getting errors. Any help is really useful to me

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am coding a twitter reply bot that replies to every tweet under a certain hashtag. I am trying to put in a feature where the bot stores every twitter id that it replies to in a text document so it never replies to them again. However, I am getting errors for some reason.

The error in the terminal:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Where my error is in the line:

```
last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
```

My code:

```
def read_last_seen(reply.txt):
    file_read = open(reply.txt, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(reply.txt, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(reply.txt, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return
```

I tried changing it around and adding integers into the text document beforehand, but nothing has worked. I am a beginner coder and any help matters.

Comment: That can't really be your code, since `reply.txt` is not a valid variable name.  But consider what happens if the file does not exist.

Comment: What do the contents of your file look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `reply.text` isn't a valid parameter name, as @Tim Roberts highlighted down in the comments.

This occurs when `file_read.read().strip()` equates to an empty string.
To prevent this, put something that `int()` will accept in your file (a string representation of a number).

My best guess would be that `read_last_seen` is being called before `store_last_seen`.

Some examples:

If the file is this:

or this:

```
   foo  baa
```

Results in an error, but if it's like this:

```
     111   22
```

It won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for the possibility that the file doesn't exist or its contents can't be converted to int. You may find this more robust:

```
# this function will implicitly return None if there's a problem
#   opening the file or converting its contents (first line only)
#   to an integer
# it does not print any error if the file is missing as that may be a valid scenario
# it reports an exception if the file content cannot be converted to int
def read_last_seen(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as data:
            return int(data.readline())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

# store the value (converted to str) in the nominated file
def store_last_seen(filename, value):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as data:
            data.write(str(value))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```